# Cannot set "is_overridable_library" option via python ["_RNA_UI"]

Tags: python, properties

I'd like to control these bools there via Python but I can't quite figure out how.

[image: both ""]

If I try something like this code, "min", "max", "soft_min" and "soft_max" work fine and update their values but "is_overridable_library" and "use_soft_limits" do not.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
obj["_RNA_UI"] = {"prop":{"min":0,"max":1,"soft_min":0,"soft_max":1,"is_overridable_library":1,"use_soft_limits":1}}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm trying to create overridable custom properties in a script. I'm able to set name, description, values, min and max but I cannot figure out how to make those properties overridable so that once linked the object's collection in another file I can play with those custom properties. I tried both 0/1 and False/True but it's not working anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, now I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: While it may be possible to edit this through `_RNA_UI`, I'd avoid using a private variable from an undocumented part of the API and instead update it through [`bpy.ops.wm.properties_edit()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.properties_edit).

Comment: I tried that but it gives me a RuntimeError. Specifically: RuntimeError: Error: Direct execution not supported. I found another thread regarding this issue, the same that gave me the idea of using "_RNA_UI". https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143975/how-to-edit-a-custom-property-in-a-python-script?rq=1

Comment: You're right. However setting `is_overridable_library` through `_RNA_UI` doesn't seem to work either, when modifying an existing property. I'll have to look at the source code as see what's going on. Sorry for causing any confusion.

Comment: Don't you worry. Appreciate that! Have a nice one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value behind `is_overridable_library` can be set through the method [`property_overridable_library_set()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.property_overridable_library_set) of an object. The following example demonstrates how to set a custom property named `"prop"` to be overridable.

```
import bpy


obj = bpy.context.object
obj.property_overridable_library_set('["prop"]', True)
```

The `use_soft_limits` is dynamically evaluated and it's not necessary to set it when using the Python API. If the `soft_max` or `soft_min` are different than the `max` or `min`, it will automatically show as enabled.

Calling [`bpy.ops.wm.properties_edit()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.properties_edit) results in an error message, because it expects that `self._last_prop` is set. This only happens in the `invoke()` function, not when calling `execute()` directly. Therefore the [execution context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#execution-context) has to be set by passing `INVOKE_DEFAULT`.

```
bpy.ops.wm.properties_edit("INVOKE_DEFAULT", data_path="object", property="prop", value="1.0", default="1.0", min=0, max=1, use_soft_limits=False, is_overridable_library=True, soft_min=0, soft_max=1, description="", subtype="NONE")
```

The downside of this is that the UI popup appears and has to be confirmed. Therefore the operator cannot be used without user interaction.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To add to this, getting whether a property is library overridable or not is also not obvious:

`bpy.context.object.is_property_overridable_library('["prop"]')`