# StringProperty specific key operator

Tags: python, scripting

I'm making a StringProperty, and I want to make specific key(e.g. Enter-Key, or others) to do some operator.
For example, if I type Enter-Key, the strings are changed by upper words.

[image]

I found there is 'options=' in StringProperty, and I think using it will be key, but still not find. Many Thanks!

```
prop = StringProperty(name="Test", options={'TEXTEDIT_UPDATE'})
```

Comment: English might be a secondary language for you?   Do you mean that you want keys like Enter to trigger a script like "ToUpper( input_text )"?   Perhaps here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143975/how-to-edit-a-custom-property-in-a-python-script

Comment: Exactly, I'm not good at English :( 
Yes. But the link is not relevant to my question..

Comment: I don't think the `options` parameter is meant for that. You'll have to define custom operators, and create custom keymap entries for them