# Image Browser for custom panel

Tags: python, add-on

How to add Image Browser to custom panel using Python or addon Serpens 3? Look like World Browser in this sample.

[image]

Comment: Should it be a panel/section in the *World Properties* tab or could it also be an area in the sidebar like this [one here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/281530/107598)?

Comment: @Blunder It doesn't really matter, but specifically I want to make a world textures switcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Property in the side panel

To create a property in the viewports side panel (N-panel)
[image: aramature selection]

use the script from this question ([How to access pose bones via python in this condition?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/281530/107598)) and  replace `select_rig` with `select_image` and these lines

```py
    # select_rig should point to an Object of type 'ARMATURE'
    bpy.types.Scene.select_rig = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name='Select Rig',
        type=bpy.types.Object, poll=scene_mychosenobject_poll)
```

with this line

```py
    bpy.types.Scene.select_image = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name='Image',type=bpy.types.Image)
```

### 2) Property in the World Properties window

```
import bpy

class SelectImagePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the World properties window"""
    bl_label = "World Image Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_select_image"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "world"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.active_object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Select an image", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, 'select_image')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectImagePanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.select_image = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name='Image',type=bpy.types.Image)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image: custom property in the world properties window]

**Related questions:**

- [How do I add a new panel to the Properties Editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214228/107598)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I meant a specific image how to change? For example "Sky Image" from World Shader. Sorry, my python skill is very beginning