# How can I create a custom property set for the objects using Python?

Tags: python, properties, custom-properties

I have to code a custom property and quantity set for objects in my Blender scene using Python. I'm a rookie in this kind of stuff, is there someone who can help me? Thank you!
I've tried to follow also this [Adding Other types of Custom Properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43785/adding-other-types-of-custom-properties/43786#43786) but it doesn't work for my aims

Comment: Hello, so what is your goal exactly ? Could you elaborate on that ? Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Hello @Gorgious and thank you for your answer. I want to get a custom pset for each object in the scene with object type, quantity, etc. I don't if I explained myself well, but I hope yes. If you need clarification let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you're using the BlenderBIM addon ? You might want to head over to https://community.osarch.org/ where there will be more people suited to answer your question

Comment: Ok, thank you for information